# How to track the line where a variable has changed it's value?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm debugging Javascript app using Chrome dev tools and wondering if there any way to catch the exact line where a variable has changed its value? Object.observe seems not able to show the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var b;
Object.defineProperty(window,'a',{
 set : function(value){
  b = value;
  alert(new Error().stack.split('\n')[2]);
 },
 get : function(){
  return b;
 },
});
a = 1;
```